# How to create generic JMS messaging to active mq and IBM mq using spring batch

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-integration, spring-batch, ibm-mq

I have a requirement to convert different text formats into XML object and send to IBM MQ. But for testing purpose I am planning to use Active mq. But my final  integration will be IBM MQ. How to make JMS template to be more generic to send across to two different message queuing platforms ?? What would be the best way make JMS as independent module??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look in to Spring Boot and its JMS [auto-configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-jms).

All what you need are `application.properties` to be configured externally.

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://192.168.1.210:9876
```

For ActiveMQ or:

spring.jms.jndi-name=java:/MyConnectionFactory

For IBM WebSphere MQ JMS adapter.

By the way you can find Spring Batch auto-configuration in Boot as well.